# FireFox not updating

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, firefox

[image: Sudo apt-get upgrade got failed on Firefox]

I was trying to upgrade the system but every time its get failed on the Firefox.
Even after the error i have tried Sudo Apt-get update then Sudo Apt-get upgrade but same error.
Please kindly help me to fix it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt --fix-missing`.

Comment: i did but same result